# show store views for a specific IP only

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view

I'm using Magento 1.9

I want to activate a new store view for our office IP only because we want to make changes in that views.

How to make that?

Comment: Are you using nginx? because I've got an idea for you if so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the template of `store view switcher` (*Language switcher template*), you can use the **Template Path Hints** feature of Magento:

> Backend > System > Configuration > Advanced section > Developer tab > Debug fieldset > Template Path Hints field

Please pay attention you need switch the **Current Configuration Scope** to needed website or store view, also I advise to specify your **IP** address here:

> Backend > System > Configuration > Advanced section > Developer tab > Developer Client Restrictions fieldset > 
>   Allowed IPs (comma separated) field

to prevent of displaying of path hints to other users.

The Magento uses the following template by default:

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml

The next step - you need to modify this template.
Please add the following line of code:

```
<?php if (3 == $_lang->getId() && '192.168.169.62' != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) continue; ?>
```

> where:
>  3 - ID of your store view;
>   192.168.169.62 - allowed IP address.

after the following line of code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
```

You can get a **ID** of *store view* here:

> Backend > System > Manage Stores